# Progress text that moves along with ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-animation, textview, android-progressbar

I have a horizontal ProgressBar in Android that animates to the current value. However, I would like to update it so that it has a TextView that shows the progress of the progress bar, and moves along with the right edge of the bar as the progress increases. I figure maybe I could create a custom ProgressBar and leverage the onDraw method somehow, but I'm not sure what the next move would be after that. Any suggestions on a better method or something that could point me in the right direction?

[A basic example of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFRks.png)

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for what I was trying to do! Inspired by the code I found on [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918947/get-the-width-of-a-the-secondaryprogress-within-a-android-progressbar) It will work for both the primary and secondary progress of a ProgressBar. What I first did was extended the ProgressBar class, and added all the constructor methods. I then Overrided the onDraw method as seen below:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //Create the paint for the text
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    textPaint.setTextSize(getHeight()/4);
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(textPrimary, 0, textPrimary.length(), bounds);

    //mTypeface is a typeface that I have being set in another function so
    //you don't have to use the default! :D
    if(mTypeface != null) {
        textPaint.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }

    //I believe this is done to be able to put values in dp
    float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    //Point to draw text for primary progress
    float percentage = getProgress() / 100f; //get the total progress
    // distance the text should be from the end of the progress in dp
    // (paddingPrimary) is number of dp
    float x = getWidth() * percentage - (paddingPrimary * density);
    // center the text vertically
    float y = getHeight() / 2 - bounds.centerY();

    //Point to draw text for secondary progress
    float percentageSecondary = getSecondaryProgress() / 100f;
    float x2 = getWidth() * percentageSecondary - (paddingSecondary * density);
    float y2 = getHeight() / 2 - bounds.centerY();

    //Draw the numbers to the canvas
    //(textPrimary and textSecondary are the text to be drawn)
    canvas.drawText(textPrimary, x, y, textPaint);
    canvas.drawText(textSecondary, x2, y2, textPaint);
}
```